# How to have two web services that is both Soap and Json run together in Spring Mvc 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap

My web Application is built on Spring Mvc 4 boot less Completely Annotation based configuration using Restful services .Now as per demand I need to integrate Soap to my existing Spring Mvc Application.**How do I configure Soap along with Restful Spring Mvc Application with annotation based configuration?**

Comment: Use Spring WS. Check the reference guide how to do the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are doing exactly that on my current project.  It is just a matter of configuring the appropriate end points in the cxf.xml.

Something like this:

```
<jaxrs:server id="restEndpoint" address="/whatever">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="restEndpointBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>


....

<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://my.url/soapserv/connect"
    id="ConnectSoap" address="/connect" serviceName="tns:connect"
    endpointName="tns:connect" implementor="#connectSoapImpl">
    <jaxws:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
    </jaxws:binding>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

For the SOAP services they are bound using the cfl.xml configuration, there are no annotations specific for this.  Obviously you will need `@Component`.

For the REST services they utilize the standard REST annotations:

```
@GET
@Path("foo/{id}")
public Response getFooId(@PathParam("id") String id)
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.PuT)
public @ResponseBody PaymentModel updateFoo(
                                       @RequestBody PaymentModel request) {
```

Comment: How do I  have this configuration in annotations using spring ws